# Combining a text box and a check box to create a search box

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

I'd like to have a search `textbox` and a `checkbox` filter for my site. The search would search for the name of a place and location while the `checkbox` would filter a activity.

Right now I have a working search `textbox` and a working `checkbox` filter but can not figure out **how to combine them**.

I'd really appreciate any help or links to tutorials etc as I'm still learning both languages and only recently started struggling and am now at a complete standstill.

## Code is fully working thanks to kstro21!

Here's the PHP

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_GET['go'])){
  if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['name'])){
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  //connect  to the database
  $db=mysql_connect  ("host", "dbo560757688",  "pw") or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error());
  //-select  the database to use
  $mydb=mysql_select_db("db560757688");
 // Fruits
$fruits = array();
foreach($_POST['fruit'] as $fruit) {
    $fruit = mysql_real_escape_string($fruit);
    $fruits[] = "'{$fruit}'"; 
}
    //-query  the database table
  $sql="SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Activity IN (" . implode(", ", $fruits) . ") AND FirstName LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' OR LastName LIKE '%" . $name ."%'";
  //-run  the query against the mysql query function
  ?>
  <?php 
//omitted code

$result=mysql_query($sql);

//close your php just after this
  }
  }
  }
?>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Activity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)):
          $FirstName=$row['FirstName'];
          $LastName=$row['LastName'];
          $Activity=$row['Activity'];
          $Email=$row['Email'];
          //-display the result of the array
          ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $FirstName ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $LastName?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Activity ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

HTML CODE

```
    <form  method="post" action="search.php?go"  id="searchform">
      <input  type="text" name="name">
      <br /> 
          <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Paintball" /> 
          Banana<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Swimming Pool" /> Apple
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Gym" /> Peach
    <br />
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</form>
```

Comment: your code looks ok, are you getting any error? what is your form html?

Comment: Will update with my HTML now, I wasn't getting any errors just didn't display.

Comment: Does this contain anything if you var_dump it? $fruits[] = "'{$fruit}'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the html code that you are printing with php has some issues, for example, the `table` tag is unclosed, the same with the first `tr`, also, you have all that code inside a for, so, it will get printed more that once, is that what you want?

first, i recommend you to try closing the for loop just after `$fruits[] = "'{$fruit}'";` and then try it again

**EDIT:**
your sql query is wrong i think, change

```
WHERE Activity LIKE (" . implode(", ", $fruits) . ")";
```

for:

```
WHERE Activity IN (" . implode(", ", $fruits) . ")";
```

you can not use `LIKE` with a comma separate values, instead, use `IN`

you can mix html and php code in the same file, so you can make something like this

```
<?php 
//...omitted code

$result=mysql_query($sql);

//close your php just after this
?>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Activity </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)):
              $FirstName=$row['FirstName'];
              $LastName=$row['LastName'];
              $Activity=$row['Activity'];
              $Email=$row['Email'];
              //-display the result of the array
          ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $FirstName ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $LastName ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Activity ?></td>
            </tr>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for that stilling having some problem displaying results and getting " syntax error, unexpected end of file in" On line 50  </tbody> as for displaying results I want one table that will display all the results. Thanks again for your help it's really appreciated I've been stuck on this for over a week!

Comment: Nope, the tbody is still causing an error and once I remove it, it still says theres an error at the end and it keeps sending an error once I remove that line until theres no code left.

Comment: please, post your the error you are getting, and i can see in your edited question that your for is unclosed, you are missing `}`

Comment: Having no problems/syntax errors, all is fully fixed but now it's not displaying any results.

Comment: what is in line 11 of search.php? if you updated your answer, i can see that `$sql` has a missing `)` at the end, just after `implode(", ", $fruits) . ""` it sould be `implode(", ", $fruits) . ")"` do you note the difference? try that and hit me back

Comment: I re-updated code once more, still not displaying any results. Code runs smoothly now. Error on line 11 was for missing a semi-colon after selecting DB.

Comment: I'm having a problem where no matter what checkbox I check I'm still getting a result for the name. FirstName = Nupe SecondName = Misc Activity = Paintball. But no matter what checkbox and search for nupe it always comes up. I also updated the code as I can't have 2 wheres I have a AND instead.

Comment: ok, try to put the `OR` within parenthesis, something like `(condition1 OR condition1) AND condition3`

Comment: RE-Arranged the SQL query as shown it was just ANDing for the LastName and FirstName was not affected. Re-Arranged and will update now as this will hopefully be useful for some people struggling Many thanks again Kstro21!